# Why this implementation of vector doesn't work for string?

Tags: c++, vector

I've tried this implentation to do same as vector stl. This implementation works for int,float,double and char. But it doesn't work for string. It shows runtime error for string.Can you please fix the problem?
Here is the github repository link: https://github.com/Nayeem-CSE-CoU/DataStructure/blob/main/vector.cpp
I've also included the code here:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class Vector
{
private:
    T *ptr;
    int pos=0;
public:
    Vector()
    {
        ptr=new T();

    }
    Vector(int n)
    {
        ptr=new T();
        pos=n;
    }
    Vector(int n,T val)
    {
        ptr=new T();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            *(ptr+pos)=val;
             pos++;
        }
    }
    void push_back(T n)
    {
        *(ptr+pos)=n;
         pos++;

    }
    void pop_back()
    {
        pos--;
        delete (ptr+pos);
    }

    T const operator [] (int i)const
    {
        
       return *(ptr+i);
         
    }
    T &operator[](int i)
    { 
        return *(ptr+i);
       
    }
    int size()
    {
        return pos;
    }
    T* begin()
    {
        return ptr;
    } 
    T* end()
    {
        return (ptr+pos);
    }

};
int main()
{
    
     Vector<string> sf;
    sf.push_back("kkk");
    sf.push_back("jjj");
    sf.push_back("Nayeem");

    
     for(auto x:sf)
     cout<<x<<" ";
     cout<<endl;

    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You could try to include string with `#include<string>`

Comment: `*(ptr+pos)` is `ptr[pos]` that is more clear. `ptr` is a pointer to a single T, not to an array of T.

Comment: @boiski string is included in bits/stdc++ header file. Yet I've included #include<string> but it doesn't work.

Comment: @NayeemHossain If you believe it doesn't work for `std::string`, it won't work for most anything else.

Comment: it doesnt work for all types, but does it actually work for any? Try to see what happens when you make copies of `Vector` and read about [the rule of 3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: @NayeemHossain *I've tried this implementation to do same as vector stl* -- A `std::vector` has correct copy semantics, while your class lacks this basic and fundamental "feature".  There is no destructor function, and forget about copying and assigning your Vector objects.

Comment: _string is included in bits/stdc++ header file_ Don't use `bits/stdc++` - it is non-standard and pulls in a load of symbols you don't need.  Instead, #include exactly the header files you need (e.g. `#include <string>`) and no more.

Comment: The code doesn't actually work for `int`, `float`, `double`, and `char`. It runs without crashing, which is not the same thing. That's just bad luck, because it's misleading.

Comment: "*This implementation works for int,float,double and char.*" - no, it does not, because it is completely mismanaging the array, regardless of the type used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> ptr=new T();
> ```

Your vector implementation creates a single dynamic object.

> ```
> void push_back(T n)
> {
>     *(ptr+pos)=n;
>      pos++;
>
> }
> ```

Your vector implementation attempts to access the pointer to a single object as if it was a pointer to an array of objects, accesses outside the bounds of that single object, and behaviour of the program is undefined.

> This implementation works for int,float,double and char

It doesn't work for any type.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to understand what is happening here

```cpp
    Vector<string> sf;   // <- calls Vector<string>::Vector() creating one new string str
    sf.push_back("kkk"); // <- places string "kkk" to the str
    sf.push_back("jjj"); // <- trying to place new string "jjj" to a place, that was never yours => results in the runtime error
    sf.push_back("Nayeem"); // <- and again
    
     for(auto x:sf)
     cout<<x<<" ";
     cout<<endl;
```

**std::vector is a dynamic array**

You need to manage your memory on more advanced level. Try to read about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)